# Cannot load group for JDBC realm

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Im being a few days struggling to create my first Security realm in glassfish V3.

My problem is that it looks like for some reason, the application does not see the one of the coulmns in the database, and my console keeps telling me that there is a syntax error. I think the table that is making me trouble is the join column(Below you will see my DB implementation).

Here i will copy the hold stack trace so you will see what is going on:

> FINE: [Web-Security] Setting Policy Context ID: old = null ctxID =
>   CHAPTER_x_12_Container_Managed_Authentication_and_Authorization/CHAPTER_x_12_Container_Managed_Authentication_and_Authorization
>   FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm:
>   (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission  GET) FINE: [Web-Security]
>   hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true FINE: SecurityContext:
>   setCurrentSecurityContext method called
>
> FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was:
>   CHAPTER_x_12_Container_Managed_Authentication_and_Authorization/CHAPTER_x_12_Container_Managed_Authentication_and_Authorization
>   FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm:
>   (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /j_security_check POST)
>   FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true FINE:
>   Logging in user [administrator@gmail.com] into realm: DBRealm using
>   JAAS module: jdbcRealm FINE: Login module initialized: class
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule
>
> SEVERE: SEC1111: Cannot load group for JDBC realm user
>   [administrator@gmail.com]. FINE: Cannot load group
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'USER_GROUP' is either not in
>   any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and
>   is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING
>   clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER
>   TABLE  statement then 'USER_GROUP' is not a column in the target
>   table.    at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:535)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:251)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:48)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnection.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnection.java:880)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:169)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.findGroups(JDBCRealm.java:478)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:312)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule.authenticate(JDBCLoginModule.java:72)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.login(AppservPasswordLoginModule.java:141)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:341)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:199)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:152)
>     at
>   com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:479)
>     at
>   com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:418)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:1015)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:615)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column 'USER_GROUP' is either
>   not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join
>   specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or
>   appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is
>   a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'USER_GROUP' is not a column
>   in the target table.  at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 50 more
>
> FINE: JAAS login complete. FINE: JAAS authentication committed. FINE:
>   Password login succeeded for : administrator@gmail.com FINE:
>   permission check done to set SecurityContext FINE: Set security
>   context as user: administrator@gmail.com FINE: [Web-Security] Policy
>   Context ID was:
>   CHAPTER_x_12_Container_Managed_Authentication_and_Authorization/CHAPTER_x_12_Container_Managed_Authentication_and_Authorization
>   FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm:
>   (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission  GET) FINE: [Web-Security]
>   hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true FINE: permission check done to
>   set SecurityContext FINE: SecurityContext: setCurrentSecurityContext
>   method called

Just to check once more, here i will paste my realm configuration and also the database and the entities used to create it.

**Realm**
[image]

**Database and entities**
[image]

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USERS", schema="ADMIN")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1244856316278032177L;
    @Id 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userid;  

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="USER_GROUP",schema="ADMIN", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="groupid", referencedColumnName= "groupid") )
    private Group group;

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }   
}
```

---

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="GROUPS", schema="ADMIN")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7274308564659753174L;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String groupid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group")
    private Set<User> users;

    public String getGroupid() {
        return groupid;
    }
    public void setGroupid(String groupid) {
        this.groupid = groupid;
    }
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }   
}
```

This is what the console displays when using the option generate Tables from entities:

> [EL Config]: The access type for the persistent class [class
>   entities.Group] is set to [FIELD]. [EL Config]: The target entity
>   (reference) class for the one to many mapping element [field users] is
>   being defaulted to: class entities.User. [EL Config]: The access type
>   for the persistent class [class entities.User] is set to [FIELD]. [EL
>   Config]: The target entity (reference) class for the many to one
>   mapping element [field group] is being defaulted to: class
>   entities.Group. [EL Config]: The alias name for the entity class
>   [class entities.Group] is being defaulted to: Group. [EL Config]: The
>   column name for element [field groupid] is being defaulted to:
>   GROUPID. [EL Config]: The alias name for the entity class [class
>   entities.User] is being defaulted to: User. [EL Config]: The column
>   name for element [field userid] is being defaulted to: USERID. [EL
>   Config]: The column name for element [field password] is being
>   defaulted to: PASSWORD. [EL Warning]: PersistenceUnitInfo CHAPTER x 12
>   Container Managed Authentication and Authorization has transactionType
>   RESOURCE_LOCAL and therefore jtaDataSource will be ignored [EL Info]:
>   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.0.1.v20100213-r6600 [EL Fine]: Detected Vendor platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.JavaDBPlatform [EL Config]:
>   Connection(25292190)--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
>     platform=>JavaDBPlatform    user name=> "user"  datasource URL=>
>   "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/studydb;create=true" )) [EL Config]:
>   Connection(18306082)--Connected:
>   jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/studydb;create=true   User: user  Database:
>   Apache Derby  Version: 10.5.3.0 - (802917)    Driver: Apache Derby
>   Network Client JDBC Driver  Version: 10.5.3.0 - (802917) [EL Config]:
>   Connection(9740137)--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
>     platform=>JavaDBPlatform    user name=> "user"  datasource URL=>
>   "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/studydb;create=true" )) [EL Config]:
>   Connection(23965177)--Connected:
>   jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/studydb;create=true   User: user  Database:
>   Apache Derby  Version: 10.5.3.0 - (802917)    Driver: Apache Derby
>   Network Client JDBC Driver  Version: 10.5.3.0 - (802917) [EL Info]:
>   file:/C:/learningJSF/CHAPTER x 12 Container Managed Authentication and
>   Authorization/build/classes/_CHAPTER x 12 Container Managed
>   Authentication and
>   Authorization_url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/studydb;create=true_user=user
>   login successful [EL Fine]: Connection(18306082)--ALTER TABLE
>   ADMIN.USER_GROUP DROP CONSTRAINT USER_GROUP_groupid [EL Fine]:
>   Connection(18306082)--ALTER TABLE ADMIN.USER_GROUP DROP CONSTRAINT
>   USER_GROUP_userid [EL Fine]: Connection(18306082)--DROP TABLE
>   ADMIN.USER_GROUP [EL Fine]: Connection(18306082)--CREATE TABLE
>   ADMIN.USER_GROUP (userid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, groupid VARCHAR(255)
>   NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (userid, groupid)) [EL Fine]:
>   Connection(18306082)--DROP TABLE ADMIN.USERS [EL Fine]:
>   Connection(18306082)--CREATE TABLE ADMIN.USERS (USERID VARCHAR(255)
>   NOT NULL, PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (USERID)) [EL
>   Fine]: Connection(18306082)--DROP TABLE ADMIN.GROUPS [EL Fine]:
>   Connection(18306082)--CREATE TABLE ADMIN.GROUPS (GROUPID VARCHAR(255)
>   NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (GROUPID)) [EL Fine]:
>   Connection(18306082)--ALTER TABLE ADMIN.USER_GROUP ADD CONSTRAINT
>   USER_GROUP_groupid FOREIGN KEY (groupid) REFERENCES ADMIN.GROUPS
>   (groupid) [EL Fine]: Connection(18306082)--ALTER TABLE
>   ADMIN.USER_GROUP ADD CONSTRAINT USER_GROUP_userid FOREIGN KEY (userid)
>   REFERENCES ADMIN.USERS (userid) [EL Config]:
>   Connection(18306082)--disconnect [EL Info]:
>   file:/C:/learningJSF/CHAPTER x 12 Container Managed Authentication and
>   Authorization/build/classes/_CHAPTER x 12 Container Managed
>   Authentication and
>   Authorization_url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/studydb;create=true_user=user
>   logout successful [EL Config]: Connection(25292190)--disconnect [EL
>   Config]: Connection(23965177)--disconnect

And this is the rest of my configuration, maybe it helps too:

[image][image]
Ill really appreciate your help.

Comment: Which version of Glassfish is this? From the stack trace, I can see that this is not v3.1.1. To find the version - start Glassfish using `asadmin start-domain domain1` (if domain1 is your domain), and then run `asadmin version`.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds The version is 3.0.1

Comment: This looks fine at first glance. Any chance that you can capture the actual SQL query used? The exception is basically suggesting that a `SELECT USER_GROUP FROM ...` is been used while it should have been a `SELECT ... FROM USER_GROUP`.

Comment: @BalusC I created the tables using JPA so to get the console message i should drop and create again, and copy paste the console messages. Ill do that, or is there other way?

Comment: @BalusC I have to mention that when i use JPA entities, the tables created go to the ADMIN schema, but i notice that if i try to do `SELECT * from USER_GROUP` at the Scrpabook, the query fails. I think eclipse is looking for that table in the schema USER. Also i have a problem, i cant use `drop table groups` because of the same reason.

Comment: Glassfish doesn't use JPA but plain JDBC for this. But if your scrapbook already fails, then I'd indeed concentrate on fixing that first at low level.

Comment: @BalusC I am confused, in what you me by low level. How can i do that? How the APP is configured to know that i want to interact with the ADMIN schema and not USER?

Comment: I mean, do not fix/test it by Glassfish/webapp. Just continue testing using the scrapbook (or any other direct DB managers) until it returns the expected results. Then replicate the DB settings in Glassfish and test by webapp. As to the schema, that's usually definied in JDBC URL or properties.

Comment: @BalusC I used again the option generate Tables from entities, so it dropped and created the tables again, above i pasted the console messages, maybe it helps. Now i have the tables again created(but empty) in the schema ADMIN. So when i use the atrribute schema at the `@Table` it works fine, but when the scrapbook use a select statement, it doesnt work because JDBC doesnt know it should look in the ADMIN schema right? So should i change the JDBC URL? where can i find that option?

Comment: May be you can write in glassfish setting ADMIN.USER_GROUP and ADMIN.USERS?

Comment: Again, Glassfish container managed security does **not** use JPA to get data from those tables. Your tables were fine. You need to set the schema in JDBC URL or properties of `jdbc/studydb` resource. How to do that depends on the DB and JDBC driver used. You seem to be using Derby/JavaDB, the schema is then the JDBC user name (at least, according the docs, I've never used it).

Comment: @BalusC At my jdbc/studydb resource options in the glassfish admin panel, i dont see an option to edit the schema name. But there is an option to add new property,should i add a property called schema and give it the value ADMIN? I uploaded above an image of how my JDBC resource looks like

Comment: According Derby/JavaDB docs, the schema is the JDBC user name. So if you want schema "admin", then you should use JDBC user name "admin".

Comment: @sfrj Try writing ADMIN.USER_GROUP and ADMIN.USERS in the realm setting.

Comment: @BalusC Ok but i am confused, should i add the property `username` in the JDBC resources? I ask because in the connection pool i already have a property called User with the value admin.

Comment: That looks fine. Then I don't know. Sorry, I haven't used JavaDB/Derby before for this, so I can't tell from experience. You could try suggestion of damluar, but based on documentation I'm not sure if JavaDB/Derby eats that.

Comment: @BalusC Yes i did as damluar said and now i dont see the exception. It was it, the realm options needed a little modification.

Comment: @damluar That was it, now i dont see the exception. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to type ADMIN.USERS and ADMIN.USER_GROUP in realm settings. It will tell GlasshFish the schema, where your tables are stored.

Comment: I am having issue with migration from 4.0 to 4.1.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686737/migration-from-glassfish-4-0-to-glassfish-4-1-1-jdbc-realm-issue